# Issue with text-overflow and float right

Tags: html, css

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DBEHJ/7/

I have a div 'header' with a title and a 'close' button that appears to the right(float: right) of the 'div'. I am using text-overflow: ellipsis for the title, but if I use it the close button(float: right) would no longer appear. This behavior is not consistent in all the browser. Below is the code

```
<div class="header"> 
    <span class="title">A Very Long Title</span>
    <span class="closeButton"> [X] </span>
</div> 

.header {
    height: 49px !important;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.header .title {
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #444444;
}

.closeButton {
    float:right; 
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Appreciate any responses.

Comment: thanks for the reply, close button appears but when a long title is given there is a overlap of title and close button like in http://jsfiddle.net/7FzCj/3/ I need the text-overflow to work in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `position:absolute` on your `.closeButton` like so :

```
.header {
    ...
    position:relative;
}

.closeButton {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QhUA6/)

**Edit**

To give your close button some room when the title is too long, you can add some `padding-right` to the header, and substract that in its `width` so that it stays 200px.

```
.header{
    ...
    width:170px;
    padding-right:30px;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7FzCj/7/)

Comment: thanks for the reply, the close button appears but when a long title is given, there is a overlap of title and close button, like show in this http://jsfiddle.net/7FzCj/3/

Answer (score 1):

Just switch the order of the title and the button and it will work

```
<div class="header"> 
    <span class="closeButton"> [X] </span>
    <span class="title">A Very Long LongTitle</span>
</div>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/DBEHJ/9/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `top`, `right`, `margin` css properties to do this.

All you've to do is set the `top` and `right` properties to **zero** and set the `margin` to auto.

I've modified @blex answer. Infact a single line of margin css.

```
.closeButton {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QhUA6/2/)

Hope it helps